# Converting D6 fieldgroup implementation to D7

Tags: 7, entities

I have a module that I'm working on that used the code:

```
  if (module_exists('fieldgroup')) {
    foreach ($content_types as $type) {
      fieldgroup_save_group($type, array('group_type' => 'standard', 'group_name' => "{$type}_group", 'label' => t("@type information", array("@type" => ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $type)))), 'settings' => array(), 'weight' => -2));
    }
  }

$crc_field = array(
  'field_name' => "{$type}_crc32",
  'type_name' => $type,
  'label' => t('CRC32 hash'),
  'type' => 'text',
  'widget_type' => 'text_textfield',
  'group' => "{$type}_group",
);
```

This is in the .install file.  What would be the appropriate method to use the D7 fieldgroup module to add an entity's fields to a fieldgroup.  Is that no longer done in .install?